# web api 404 error after hosting in existing web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a Web Api and I created a directory/folder(myWebApi) on the server where my web application(www.mydomain.com) is already hosted. I Hosted/uploaded that web api in that folder **myWebApi** and when i try to access

```
www.mydomain.com/myWebApi/api/mycontroller/action
```

its returning a 404 error

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

here is my WebApiConfig

```
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "myWebApi/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi1",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Please give me solution.

Comment: Have you registered the routes in `Application_start{GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)}`? Also, try switching the order- Move `DefaultAPI1` on top and then `DefaultAPI`. Alternatively, you can use `Route Attributes`

Comment: yes i have registered routes in Application_start{GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)} and i tried switching order but did not work.

Comment: i have tried Route Attribute also but not working.